# How can I change an XML element value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have an XML DB and I have been able to parse the XML using DOM with JS. The thing I am unable to figure out is, how can I change a value in my XML db?

I tried using:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("COMMENT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="text";
```

But this does not changes the actual DB. When I refresh my page, it gives me the same old value again.

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Edit:

I am making changes only on the client page and not sending the data back to make relevant changes in database itself.

I understand I should use AJAX or something, but could you please give me directions on what I should read or some examples where I can learn?

Comment: what do you mean with "XML database" ?

Comment: How are you writing the change to the "db"?  The value you are changing in that try is merely a copy that has been loaded into your program and not the real data would be my guess.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. The changes are just in client page. I did not knew about that. 
So, can you suggest what should i do to make changes in the XML itself. 
My XML file is probably not going to be very huge, but still it would be 200-250 records long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to XML with JavaScript, only load a copy of the XML DOM into memory and manipulate that copy. Obviously that is destroyed when the JS instance restarts (reloading the page) or you re-load from the original file.

If the XML is on the server, you will need a server-side language such as PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, etc. to write anything to disk on the server. That code executes on the server, not in the browser.

- [Reading and Writing XML in c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx)
- [XML for PHP developers, Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xmlphp1.html)
- [Ruby on Rails and XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/x-dw-x-rubyonrailsxml.html)

To communicate between your JavaScript code and your server-side code, AJAX is the answer. [A List Apart has a good resource for getting started](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/gettingstartedwithajax). The simplest model that comes to mind is using AJAX to send the complete, modified XML chunk to server-side code, which simply saves it.

If you are dealing with huge files and frequent updates, you may want to consider using AJAX to send manipulation instructions to the server-side code, which execute the changes and save the file.

Comment: THanks Rex. 

I believe i have to read about AJAX first to do this. 

Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

You've told us basically no relevant info, but most likely you're just changing the client page, and making no effort to send back (e.g. with a form or AJAX) the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save db after changes. It is not possible with DOM and JS on Web Browser, so you should use AJAX or sth similar to process XML